# how to actually skip statements in if..elseif..else..endif condition

Tags: if-statement, vbscript, nested

```
if (some condition) --suppose this gets true
    ....
    ....
elseif (some condition)--this also gets false
    ...
    ...
else 
    ... --this else condition becomes false
    ...
    if (some condition)
        ..
    else
        ..
    endif-- stops execution when it gets here,doesnt moves on to next endif

endif
```

now what I want to do is to skip the else part. For which I am skipping it until it gets an endif keyword. But it stops the execution when it gets the first endif in the else part. How to skip that endif so that it matches the exact endif of a if.
Its really confusing please help...

Comment: use return statement when condition is true in if

Comment: @NiravRanpara VBScript doesn't have a `Return` statement. You have to use `WScript.Quit`, `Exit Sub` or `Exit Function`, depending on the context.

Answer (score 3):

You need to get your conditional logic straight:

```
magicNumber = 42

If magicNumber = 42 Then
    wscript.echo "Magic number is 42!"
ElseIf magicNumber > 23 Then
    wscript.echo "Magic number is more than 23"
Else
    wscript.echo "Magic number is 23 or less"
    If magicNumber <= 0
         wscript.echo "Woah! Magic number is negative!"
    else
         wscript.echo "Phew, at least Magic number is not zero or negative"
    End if
    wscript.echo "Bye!"
End if
wscript.echo "End."

' Output: 
' Magic number is 42!
' End.
```

Because the first condition is `True`, none of the other conditions will be tested and executed.

Comment: Thanks for this.  I actually never realized it would drop out of the ENTIRE code block.  I always thought it would go to the final else statement if the others were false.